# Subtract months from a given date in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date, date-math

I need to subtract 21 months from a given date.

My solution as given below only takes me to the first month of the given year :(

```
[a,b,c]= datevec(date);
b= b-21;
datestr(datenum(a,b,c)) %--> 11-Jan-2011 (WRONG).
```

I want the answer to be 11-June-2009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go via date numbers rather than date vectors and use `addtodate`:

```
>> d = datenum(date);
>> e = addtodate(d, -21, 'month');
>> datestr(e)

ans =

11-Jun-2009
```